# SQLite and getting back specific row

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not really sure what my problem is. I have tried everything. Here is my code:

```
public Album getAlbum(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.d("ID number", id + "");
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALBUM + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("Count", cursor.getCount() + "");
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){         
        Album album = new Album(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),Utility.getPhoto(cursor.getBlob(8)));
        cursor.close();
        return album;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am printing out the values:

```
05-08 03:14:03.066: E/album position(1285): 1
05-08 03:14:03.156: D/ID number(1285): 1
05-08 03:14:03.156: D/Count(1285): 0
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{sparkdesignz.momenture/sparkdesignz.momenture.AlbumInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In the log file above I show what I am trying to get (position). I show it again in the method, then I show th value from my cursor. Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Here is my full log

```
05-08 03:14:03.166: W/dalvikvm(1285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sparkdesignz.momenture/sparkdesignz.momenture.AlbumInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at sparkdesignz.momenture.AlbumInfoActivity.onCreate(AlbumInfoActivity.java:48)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-08 03:14:03.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is but you should start off by removing the first coursor.moveToFirst(). You already have it in your if-statement.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: also post your full code

Comment: i can resolve this problem but can u please tell me what you want to achieve with the above code can explain

Comment: check your AlbumInfoActivity.java:48

Comment: getAlbum() isn't even being called. The problem is in AlbumInfoActivity.onCreate().

Comment: whats located here ?? AlbumInfoActivity.java:48 ??? i mean what piece of line is there??/

Comment: Its none of the above but thatnks. The problem was increasing the database version by 1.

Answer (score 0):

48th line in your in AlbumInfoActivity.java of onCreate function  contain a variable which is not initialized, check what is it..

Comment: The reason for that is because the album is coming back null